# How to use apiFetch to get author information in Gutenberg properly?

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, block-editor

I'm trying to create author info block for posts.

So I created a block and tried to use redux to get author info,
but could get only author id:

```
const applyWithSelect = withSelect(
    (select, props) => {
        return {
            authorId: select('core/editor').getCurrentPostAttribute('author')
        }
    }
);
```

Then I tried to use apiFetch to get author info by its id:

```
const authorApi = apiFetch( { path: `/wp/v2/users/${authorId}` } ).then(data => {console.log(data)});
```

So it's actually working, I'm getting all author information in my console.
But how to get that data values to map through it?

What should I insert inside `then()`?
I think I should create an empty array and push that data values inside of it.

But I don't know how, my knowledge is not enough.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out how to do it.
Just call fetchApi in componentDidMount and then create a new state in your component and add the response to this state when the request is done:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {},
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    apiFetch( { path: '/wp/v2/users/1' } )
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
}
```

then in render:

```
const { data } = this.state;
```

finally in return for example avatar of author:

```
<div className={className}>
    { data.avatar_url ? (<img src={data.avatar_url['24']} />) : (<></>) }
</div>
```